# Coding for iOS from Linux/Windows

Tags: ios, macos, virtualbox, vnc

Currently, I'm working on an iMac on an iOS project, using an iOS device (and not a simulator). Using the device is essential because I have an external Bluetooth device which I'm using at my code. I'm gonna be away from my office for 6 days and I need to work while away. My laptop uses Fedora and I can also have access to Windows machines (but not Apple ones). Xcode, the IDE for coding for iOS, (of course) works only on Mac OS X.

**My question is: How can I continue coding for iOS from Fedora or Windows on these 6 days?**

I saw some answers to similar questions and the most highly-rated answers involve buying a Mac mini and selling it when no longer needed. I think my case is kinda different as I have **remote** access to an iMac. I googled for USB forwarding, so that I can redirect my laptop's USB to the iMac's one, but it's not very popular and the results I got seemed to be unreliable. Is it worth it trying to install Mac OS X on VirtualBox? I think it's very unlikely that I'll manage to set up everything successfully, many users seemed to have problems with this.

I'll probably end up buying (and selling) the Mac mini, but I thought it might be worth asking here first.

Some hardware info (for installing Mac OS X through VirtualBox):
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9600  @ 2.80GHz
Graphics card: nVidia Corporation G96 [GeForce 9600M GT] (rev a1)

Thanks in advance for any replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can test parts of your work in isolation using the simulator and can get by with only  the occasional run on a device then you could look at making an ad hoc build and installing onto your device using 'over the air' distribution from a web link on a public facing site.

There are a number of sites that walk you through such provision/build steps, such as:-

http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/

...which could be managed by 'remoting in', although speed may be frustrating.

If you need to test on a device more than once or twice a day, this could be too inefficient and maybe a foray into Mac Mini trading offers the best bet!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I'll get too frustrated by using the remote access, so I'll probably buy a used Macbook from eBay (and sell it once I get back). The Mac minis seem to have approximately the same price and I'll also need a monitor and keyboard/mouse, so Macbook seems to be a better option.